# Creating and opening a new excel file using open file dialog

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, openfiledialog

I have a open file dialog from where i will open excel files and download data into them. But in the open file dialog if I give a new file name and click on the OK button, it says File not found. Instead I want to create a file if the given file name does not exist and continue with my work. How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: open file dialog is only for opening files.  Save file dialog is for saving files the user can specify the name of the new file.  If you want to create a new excel file and put data in it I would use the open xml sdk or npoi to create an excel file with data and save it

Comment: @KenTucker... i am getting the same issue with save file dialog also.

Comment: post some code so we can help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `OpenfileDialog` control checks to make sure that the file exists. To stop this happening, before you show the dialog, or when your calling form is loaded, add this line .. changing "OpenFileDialog1" to whatever yours is called.

```
OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = False
```

Then, when you press ok, the filename you typed is returned to your application. Of course, you'll need to check if the file exists yourself and decide what to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... found out the solution by following your instructions.

Comment: No worries. If you think the question is answered, click the tick next to it so that other users can see that this is an accepted answer. Cheers :-)